# Python regex version in single quotes

Tags: python, regex, version

Given the input below, I'd like a Python compatible regex who's output is the second version value ... "8.20.233". I've tried best to cobble together a solution from many searches, but I just cannot seem to hit upon the right combination. Thanks for looking.

```
cask 'logitech-options' do
  if MacOS.version <= :sierra
    version '7.14.77'
    sha256 'e4df55642e04139fc93d955e949bf736196a404ed067d87f8de7eb9ac9117ece'
  else
    version '8.20.233'
    sha256 '52427d5fa9f0e0508c3414906212774b7ae142450d6dcf90fe1a4d6b51449c67'
  end
```

Comment: what is _special_ about the second value ? second ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but as far as the regex goes I'm guessing that it's the second version string after the word "version". As for the need to resolve the value, the second version string is the current version of the product. The first value is for macOS Sierra 10.12 and below. Without finding that value I cannot programmatically download the current version of the software.

Comment: regex doesn't know the difference

Comment: whats to be trustede `else` indicating version needed ? so need the _else_  version, yes ?

Comment: yes in this case if else is present, then the next version will be the correct one.

Comment: theen how do you parse `else`, need know, yes ? or is `else.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)` cutting it ?

Comment: @Amin Guermazi nailed it with `else\s+version\s+'([\d\.]*?)'`

Comment: nailed it with `else\s+sha256\s+'.*?'\s+version\s+'([\d\.]*?)'` yes ? `then the next version will be the correct one` could reduce to `else\s+.*?version\s+'([\d\.]*?)'` nail it , yes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

s = """cask 'logitech-options' do
  if MacOS.version <= :sierra
    version '7.14.77'
    sha256 'e4df55642e04139fc93d955e949bf736196a404ed067d87f8de7eb9ac9117ece'
  else
    version '8.20.233'
    sha256 '52427d5fa9f0e0508c3414906212774b7ae142450d6dcf90fe1a4d6b51449c67'
  end"""
result = re.findall(r"'([\d\.]*?)'", s)

print(result[1])
```

And output:

```
8.20.233
```

### EDIT

If you want to get 8.20.233 as the first match, change your code as follows:

```
import re

s = """cask 'logitech-options' do
  if MacOS.version <= :sierra
    version '7.14.77'
    sha256 'e4df55642e04139fc93d955e949bf736196a404ed067d87f8de7eb9ac9117ece'
  else
    version '8.20.233'
    sha256 '52427d5fa9f0e0508c3414906212774b7ae142450d6dcf90fe1a4d6b51449c67'
  end"""
result = re.findall(r"else\s+version\s+'([\d\.]*?)'", s)

print(result[0])
```

Comment: First, thank you. and wow, that puts me much, much closer. In my ignorance, I may have asked the question wrong/imprecisely. The way I've tested regex for the what I'm working on (an AutoPkg download recipe) is to put the input and regex string into https://regex101.com. If I do that with this regex, it seams to capture just the 7.14.77. I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: No, it highlights both `7.14.77` and `8.20.233`. Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/eZM9tC/1)

Comment: Sorry again for my ignorance. Trying not to be completely useless .. https://regex101.com/r/m9oHP2/1

Comment: Its because you are missing the 'g' flag after the regex. It means the regex mustn't stop at first match.

Comment: See [here](https://i.imgur.com/E6ZrsYz.png) to know where it is.

Comment: Thanks again. I think was I need to do now is just figure out how to add the "else" to the to the  the "version +'(.+)'" from above to make the 8.20.233 the "first matched sub-pattern" that I now understand is required for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to decide how strict to be in your regex. A couple of examples:

```
rgx1 = re.compile(r"version +'(.+)'")              # Pretty loose.
rgx2 = re.compile(r"version +'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'")   # More strict.
```

And you haven't given us enough information to sensibly distinguish between the two version numbers in the input text. The appropriate way to do that would depend on the specifics of your use case.

```
rgx2.findall(TEXT)  # ['7.14.77', '8.20.233']
```

Comment: Considering the version numbers won't go backward, is it possible to say that the string has to start with greater than or equal to 8? That would solve the issue for a year or three. is there a way to simply output the second result?

Comment: @peet Sure, just take the last item: `rgx2.findall(TEXT)[-1]`. You can also adjust the regex easily to require that the digits start with `8`.